# Calling external javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck in a problem which might seem foolish but please bear with me. I am calling an external JavaScript function from an html page. Turns out it's not working. But when I write the whole JavaScript in the html page instead of sourcing, it works fine.

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
<button onclick=func()>submit</button>
```

External javascript

```
function func(){
    // do something
}
```

But when i change to inline javascript it works.

Comment: You have some code?

Comment: Please read the *"Help others reproduce the problem"* section of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: share your code

Comment: Post your HTML and the external javascript and explain what you are seeing that is wrong and what your expected result it.

Comment: _Any idea what might be wrong?_ It could be that issue, that we can tell you if you share the code.

Comment: how you can pass the script into html page

Comment: Sorry that doesn't look like a valid HTML. Can you please read [ask] and follow the instructions given to post a good code?

Comment: Keep coding in the html file until you are able to do it in an external js file. That won't be long if you follow a tutorial. Try to figure out theses issues yourself and keep questions for real technical issues.

Comment: Take a few moments and actually provide the real code you're using which demonstrates the problem.  Just vaguely describing your code like this doesn't help.

Comment: We are trying to correct your question format, but you still keep reverting to the wrong way. Did you even read the description on how to insert code?

Answer (score 1):

`func()` in the HTML needs to be in quotes. Like so:

```html
<button onclick="func()">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This often happens as the `js` file which is sourced in the `script src=""` tag is loaded from the local memory of the browser. Even if you change it, the changes might not reflect in your `html`. You can check this by making some changes in your `js` file, refreshing your webpage and checking the script from your `sources` tab in your developer tools.

For changes to reflect immediately, do *either* of the following,

1. Make changes and press `ctrl`+`F5` to refresh the webpage. This forces the browser to load the `js` file again.
2. You can try renaming the `js` file and changing the name in the script tag too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your javascript file with your HTML file
either at the end(of body) or in the top(in head)

```
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
or,
<head>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
```